# How can I send a variable to a function when calling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I send the variable `message` to the function `callmessage` when it is called?

```
<script>
var message = 'hello and this is your message'

callmessage(); // how can i send the variable 'message' to the function when I call it

function callmessage() {
   console.log(the text sent when the function was called)
}
</script>
```

Comment: Odd question since you have lots of other JS posts where you're passing arguments. Are you hoping for something specific, like a pointer that can alter the `message` variable?

Comment: In this case, `var message = '...'` is declared outside of the scope of `function callmessage() { }`, so it's already available and doesn't need to be sent.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
var message = 'hello and this is your message'

callmessage(message);

function callmessage(x) {
   console.log(x);
}
</script>
```

If you're just getting into javascript, I highly recommend looking at a few things that will help you write better code:

- https://eslint.org/
- https://github.com/airbnb/javascript
- ES6 features like modules, arrow functions, etc. and how https://babeljs.io/ can be used to transpile ES6 to ES5 for use in browsers now

Answer (score 1):

You send it as an argument to the function like:

```js
var message = 'hello and this is your message'
callmessage(message); // how can i send the message variable
function callmessage(themessage) {
  console.log(themessage)
}
```

I would *highly* recommend reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions